# Macbook Pro not detecting sd card

Tags: macos, sdhc

My sister has a sdhc card that has worked for a while, but when she tries to open it on her macbook pro, it doesn't detect it or mount it. It will work fine on other peoples computers, but not hers. Is there a way to fix this? Maybe manually mounting it from a terminal?

Comment: Did that SDHC card *ever* work on her Macbook Pro?

Comment: Yes it did. It just started acting up now. It is rather hard to get details from my sister.

Comment: I had the same problem on my Mac Pro. Rebooting solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out all they had to do was reset the pram.

Comment: [How to Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to me, turns out the lock switch on the side of the card was ever so slightly pushed toward the lock position.  Pushed it back up, worked great!  Probably not the solution for everyone, but worked for me!!

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: This turned out to be my problem too - check this before reporting to more difficult solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening looking at it in the Disk Utility app (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app) and see if it shows up there.

Open the Console app (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app) before you put the card in, clear the contents of the window and then put the card in. Do you get any messages/

Comment: It did not show up in the disk utility app, even after several reboots. No messages showed up when the card was inserted. She is just going to take it back to the store.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem couple of months back . I went to the Apple Store and they said they will need to replace the logic board. Works fine after replacement.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me was blowing into the SD card slot - apparently when enough dust collects there, it will isolate the card pins and system doesn't even recognize it then :).